# centering javascript pop-up window

Tags: javascript, popup, centering

Here's my JavaScript code.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname) {
    if (! window.focus) return true;
    var href;
    if (typeof mylink  == 'string')
        href=mylink;
    else
        href = mylink.href;
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=yes');
    return false;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Using just the code above, the pop up appears exactly how i want it, but it appears snuggly tucked into the upper left hand corner.  I want the pop up to appear centered.

I've tried several suggestions on this website (such as:

```
var left = screen.width / 2 - w / 2;
var top = screen.height / 2 - h / 2;
```

but plugging anything else into the code i already have makes the pop up open in a new tab of the same browser (ignoring the pop up function).

That's the problem I came here to have solved.

Additionally, I'd like to fade the background to draw the reader's focus to the pop up.  Is there a javascript snippet that i can toss in that will do so?

Comment: why did this get down voted. The he is asking a question there is an answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function popupW(mylink, windowname) {
    var href;
    var w = h = 500;
    var left = (screen.width/2) - (w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2) - (h/2);

    if(!window.focus) {
        return true;
    }

    if(typeof mylink == 'string') {
        href = mylink;
    } else {
        href = mylink.href;
    }

    window.open(href, windowname, 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=yes, top='+top+', left='+left);
    return false;
}
popupW('http://google.com', 'google');
```

Fading of the background window can be done by creating overlay.

```
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.setAttribute('id', 'overlay');
document.body.appendChild(overlay);
```

With following css style:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: I got the pop up centered, thank you!  however, i'm not able to get any response from the overlay code.  I suspect i'm doing something stupid like putting the code in the wrong place or putting the wrong name on my CSS document.  Here's what i did:

Copied and pasted the first code into the <script> section of my index page.  I copied and pasted the second code (css style) into a new document and saved it as "overlay.css"

However, when i click one of the links and bring up the pop up window, the background page doesn't fade.  What have i done wrong?  I've never used CSS before.

Comment: You should add the javascript code into the popup function (just before the `return false` statement). Also you should listen to closing or unfocusing popup to hide the overlay.

Comment: But I recommend using some javascript library instead of pop-up windows. For example [modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) if you're use Twitter bootstrap or jQuery UI or even one of the lightbox clones which support iframes. It's easier to use and less irritating to user. I personally am usually really mad if the browser pops up a new window on my screen. Also in some browsers pop-ups are disabled entirely.

Comment: I had originally attempted to use both fancybox and shadowbox to do the background fade/popup window.  I could get neither to work with the image mapping hotspots i was using as clickable links :(

Believe me, i would love to use modal windows instead of popups- they're cleaner and far less amateur looking.  But for now, until i can do some dedicated reading on the subject, they're above my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
    if (typeof(mylink) !== 'string') mylink=mylink.href;
    var l=(screen.width-500)/2, t=(screen.height-500)/2;
    window.open(mylink, windowname, 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1,left='+l+',top='+t);
    return false;
}

popup('http://heera.it', 'hit');
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VXY9/3/)